# Cómo guardar el nombre de una imagen C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un método con el cual obtengo una imagen por medio de una consulta a la base de datos, deseo obtener el nombre de esa imagen para luego almacenar solo el nombre en otra tabla. El siguiente es el método con el cual obtengo la imagen:

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");
            
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT NOMBRE_FOTO FROM TBL_FOTOS", connect);

            SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_FOTOS");

            byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];

            dp.Fill(ds, "TBL_FOTOS");

            DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_FOTOS"].Rows[0];

            MisDatos = (byte[])myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);

            pbVista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

           
        }
```

El siguiente es el query para la creación de la tabla de donde obtengo el nombre de la imagen:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_FOTOS (
    NOMBRE_FOTO VARCHAR(MAX),
    ID VARCHAR(9),
    FOTO IMAGE
)
```

Lo que requiero es un metodo el cual me permita almancenar el nombre de la imagen que obtengo en la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_FOTOS_DISP (
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Al organizar el método en el botón de Registrar queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_FOTOS_DISP");
            byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];

            DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_FOTOS_DISP"].Rows[0];

            string nombreFoto = (string)myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];

            var command = connect.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "insert into TBL_FOTOS_DISP_ values(@nombreFoto)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombreFoto", nombreFoto);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
```

Y esto me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 2:**

Al ejecutar las ultimas modificaciones de la respuesta, estoy presentando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si `myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"]` contiene el nombre de la foto se puede recuperar así:

```
string nombreFoto = (string) myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];
```

Luego insertarla en la otra tabla de esta forma:

```
var command = connect.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "insert into TBL_FOTOS_DISP values(@nombreFoto)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombreFoto",nombreFoto);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Actualización**

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");

  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT NOMBRE_FOTO FROM TBL_FOTOS", connect);

  SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

  DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_FOTOS");

  byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];

  dp.Fill(ds, "TBL_FOTOS");

  DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_FOTOS"].Rows[0];

  string nombreFoto = (string) myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];
  var command = connect.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "insert into TBL_FOTOS_DISP values(@nombreFoto)";
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombreFoto", nombreFoto);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  MisDatos = (byte[]) myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);

  pbVista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

}
```

Comment: Revisa mi ultima actualización, probé lo que me mencionas en esta respuesta pero me devuelve null al ejecutar

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta y agregué el código completo

Comment: Y si lo deseo hacer aparte en la otra función de registrar, puedo copiar el código al evento del botón `btnRegistrar_Click`?

Comment: Sí, ya me fijé que estás usando otra función. Lo que pasa en la otra función es que estás usando la tabla `TBL_FOTOS_DISP` y tiene que ser `TBL_FOTOS` . Por que de `TBL_FOTOS` se lee el nombre de la imagen.

Comment: Puedes actualizar la pregunta o si quieres puedo pasar el código a la otra función

Comment: Para hacerlo más fácil primero prueba si funciona  el código en `btnObtener_Click` revisa si se inserta el nombre en la otra tabla.

Comment: Disculpa que hice una modificación en el nombre del DataAdapter de la pregunta inicial, afecta algo en la respuesta que me colocaste ?

Comment: No afecta, solo asegurate  de actualizar el código de la respuesta si copias y pegas.

Comment: Voy hacer el cambio también en tu respuesta para no generar futuras confusiones

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115853/discussion-between-lobos-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo necesitas grabar el nombre del archivo en la otra tabla puedes utilizar este código:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");
        
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT TBL_FOTOS_DISP(NOMBRE) SELECT NOMBRE FROM TBL_FOTOS WHERE ID = 'FOTO5'", connect);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Donde 5 puedes cambiarlo por el ID de la imagen que vas a manipular.

Comment: El `ID` de la tabla es autoincremental, afectara algo en colocarle la condición ?

Comment: Si tienes razón, no había visto lo del autoincremental, he corregido la respuesta, había considerado que ese campo era el que relacionaba ambas tablas.

Comment: De donde voy a obtener la condición `ID = 'FOTO5'`?

Comment: El ID de la tabla TBL_FOTOS, entiendo que es un valor único para identificar a una imagen, suponiendo que hay varios registros en esa tabla, entonces tú decidirías de donde viene ese valor, si de un formulario u otro proceso, es para elegir la foto de donde obtendrías el nombre..

Comment: El nombre lo obtengo de la tabla `TBL_FOTOS` en el campo `NOMBRE_FOTO` lo que requiero es guardarlo en la tabla `TBL_FOTOS_DISP` en el campo `NOMBRE`